# compass cannot compile completely using compass v0.12.6+sass v3.3.1?

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass

what i mean is that using command: **gem install sass v3.3.1** and  then **gem install compass v0.12.6** .and i run the command: **compass watch ...**. It can compile my sass file but not completely because when I open my html, it is not working.

gem list:

**local gems**
bigdecimal (1.2.0)

chunky_png (1.3.4)

compass (0.12.6)

ffi (1.9.10 x64-mingw

fssm (0.2.10)

io-console (0.4.2)

json (1.7.7)

minitest (4.3.2)

multi_json (1.11.2)

psych (2.0.0)

rake (0.9.6)

rb-fsevent (0.9.5)

rb-inotify (0.9.5)

rdoc (4.0.0)

sass (3.3.1, 3.2.19)

test-unit (2.0.0.0)

Thanks.

Comment: I use compass v0.12.6 because my company wants us to use that version.but i spent two days and still cannot figure out what to do with it and what's wrong with it. It just cannot compile correctly(can compile to css but not completely).Help!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't think compass versions < 1.0 are compatible with sass version 3.3.x